# Why does Marty give the colt peacemaker to Seamus at the end of Back to the Future Part 3?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-part-3

Everything seems to have some sort of meaning, but the peacemaker just feels random.

Comment: Part of the running joke WRT Seamus's hat, IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion it is kind of memorabilia which Marty is leaving behind for Seamus.

We can also interpret it as a symbol of courage which Marty stood up for and defeated Tannen.

Since generation of McFly has always been bullied by that of Tannen's, it was a symbolic message from Marty to Seamus for being courageous so that coming generation of McFly can stand up for themselves.

Also because Seamus didn't have a gun and Marty didn't need it back in 1985.

Comment: Though he mentions just trading it in for a new hat…..